# Can I make the system reserve for partitions smaller?

Tags: filesystem, ext4

To my knowledge Ubuntu creates a system reserve on partitions that take up 5% of the partition capacity. On 8 TB drives system reserve takes up about 380 gigs. I double checked this in df and can calculate the missing gigs. I have four 8 TB partitions and am losing 1.5 TB of storage space. Is there a way to make ubuntu use a smaller percentage for the system reserve?

Answer (score 2):

### `mkfs.ex4` to create a linux `ext4` file system

When you use `mkfs.ext4` you will create a new file system (and the data in the partition will be lost). You must **backup** all data, that you cannot afford to lose, before doing it.

You can use the option `-m` to specify the reserved percentage, for example to get 3%,

```
sudo mkfs.ex4 -m 3 /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the device letter and n is partition number, for example `/dev/sda1`.

From `man mkfs.ex4`

```
   -m reserved-blocks-percentage
          Specify the percentage of the filesystem blocks reserved for the
          super-user.   This  avoids  fragmentation, and allows root-owned
          daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to  function  correctly
          after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the
          filesystem.  The default percentage is 5%.
```

### `tune2fs` to modify a linux `ext4` file system

When you use `tune2fs` you will modify an existing file system (and the data in the partition should be preserved). But you should **backup** all data, that you cannot afford to lose, before doing it.

You can use the option `-m` to specify the reserved percentage, for example to get 3%,

```
sudo tune2fs -m 3 /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the device letter and n is partition number, for example `/dev/sda1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and you can change the percentage on each disk with the following parameters
Example:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1
```

where 0 is percentage size

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'Reserved block count'
```

check reserved block count