# My /Root says I only have like I am low on space, someone help me figure this out?

Tags: disk-usage, ext4

My `/dev/sda6` says I only have 4.7G available but still `use%` is 99? It does not make sense.

Can someone help me with this?

```
waybackdrm@dolansroadbike:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           784M  2.5M  781M   1% /run
/dev/sda6       260G  242G  4.7G  99% /
```

I try the following:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

doesn't seem to do anything?

Any feedback? also let me know if I need more screenshots?

Comment: FYI:  `/root` is a different directory to the root / directory.  `/root` is the home directory of the root user (which is disabled by default in Ubuntu) so when you mention the root ('/') directory ensure you separate the two with at least a space (better if more than that too)

Answer (score 1):

Because some of the space is reserved. You can check it by running

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda6 | grep 'Reserved'
```

By default 5% will be reserved for the root, which is `260G * 0.05 = 13G`. That means the available space to you is only ~247G. ext4 itself also needs some space for its metadata, so you're already almost full

To [reduce the reserved space](https://askubuntu.com/q/1014132/253474) run `tune2fs -m$PERCENT $PARTITION`. For example to reduce it to 1% in your case run

```
tune2fs -m1 /dev/sda6
```

But it's only a **temporary solution**. Having a full disk is not a good idea anyway since there isn't enough space for a contiguous region for new files or to move old files around, so fragmentation will increase significantly. You should consider cleaning up your disk and/or upgrade disk space

See

- [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7950/44425)
- [Partitioning - Is 5% reserved blocks required/recommended?](https://serverfault.com/q/933157/343888)

Comment: He has a full disk, lowering the reserved space is not going to help much.

Comment: @HappyTux of course it's not a good idea but it gives the OP sometime while waiting for upgrading the disk. Especially if that's a company PC then it's not easy to upgrade at all, processes are just so slow

Comment: okay thanks for the feedback and help! oh and I forgot to mention it's a dual boot PC, running Ubuntu and Windows 10.

Comment: @DolanMcElmurry it has nothing to do with the OS. It's just a feature of the file system. And if my answer helps you, please click the green check mark to [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: He has a full disk, lowering the reserved space is not going to help much.  <HappyTux> said, true. I will do more digging. I see some areas where I can get rid of stuff,etc to get more space.

Comment: Interesting enough I see in other posts about Low disc space many insights that I don't see here to solving said Low Space. So I might as well just delete this question.